# What is the cost of many null-foreign keys in a model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Post model, an Image model, and a Channel model. I have a foreign key in the Image model connected to the Post model. Additionally, I am trying to add a nullable foreign key connected to the Channel model.

```
   class Image(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        news = models.ForeignKey(News, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        message = models.ForeignKey(Message, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        file = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/',
                                    processors=[Transpose()],
                                    format='JPEG',
                                    options={'quality': 50},
                                    blank=True)
```

My concern is that the channel field will be mostly null as I only need one image per channel. But the image has to be connected with a Post. So each one channel has one image that is connected to the post. However, There will be incompariably more posts and images than a channel, so the channel field in the Image model will be wasted most of the time.

Another solution I thought of is creating a new image model exclusively for the Channel model and when the new image instance is created, manually copy the image from the original image-post connected instance.

```
class ChannelImage(models.Model):
            channel = models.OneToOneField(Channel)
            post = models.OneToOneField(Post)
            file = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/',
                                        processors=[Transpose()],
                                        format='JPEG',
                                        options={'quality': 50},
                                        blank=True)
//copy a file from the original post
```

So my question is what the cost of having so many wasted null foreign keys in a model is? Is it okay to have many wasted foreign keys in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First of all

There is nothing technically bad about to have a model with a property with null value in a lot of rows.

#### About your design

You talk about two designs:

```
Image -> Channel  ( image references channel )
ChannelImage -> Image ( new model to store  channel image )
```

But, in your post, you say:

> So each one channel has one image that is connected to the post.

But, What is wrong with?

```
Channel -> Image ( channel reference image )
```

With this approach, you don't lose information, because `Image` has still connected to `Post`.

#### Answer

In my opinion, this is the way:

1. Apply [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to your scenario.
2. Change natural keys to [Surrogate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) (Id's). Maybe you want to keep some natural keys.
3. Check your design has not issues with performance (maybe do you need to aggregate some data in a field to make some queries faster). Null values are not a performance problem.

#### Bonus track

Since django 2.2 you can write [index condition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/indexes/#condition), it means that, if you need to index a model by a property with a lot of nulls, you can index, if you want, only for rows with some value on this property, like not null.

> If the table is very large and your queries mostly target a subset of rows, it may be useful to restrict an index to that subset. Specify a condition as a Q. For example, condition=Q(pages__gt=400) indexes records with more than 400 pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider two main aspects when thinking about the cost; time and memory.

There is a good [post](http://bonesmoses.org/2014/05/14/foreign-keys-are-not-free/) about the Foreign Key costs for postgresql. A test is performed about the effect of Foreign Keys to the time performance where there is only one dynamic parameter. The results are as below:

> The only parameter this function accepts, is the amount of tables it should create that reference this source table. [...] these timings were collected several times, and averaged 2961ms, 3805ms, 4606ms, 5089ms, and 5785ms after three runs each. As we can see, after merely five foreign keys, performance of our updates drops by 28.5%. By the time we have 20 foreign keys, the updates are 95% slower!

When thinking about memory cost, that won't be real much of a deal when you think of today's computers. But you can also consider creating an intersection table instead of using Foreign Keys if you think you will have a lot of null Foreign Key fields.